# Multi threaded access to map object that won't be modified after creation

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the best practice for creating a `Map<>` object that will be access from multiple threads, but that will not be modified after initialization?

Would it be:

1. use a `ConcurrentHashMap<>` object
2. create a normal `HashMap<>` object and wrap this in a `Collections#unmodifiableMap` call? Only retaining a reference to the `unmodifiableMap` and not the original `HashMap<>`.
3. something else.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: I'd go for the second one, or just write the class so that there's no write access to it.

Comment: That was my gut feeling as well, but I was unsure if reading the `HashMap` concurrently would have any unintended side effects.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the map going to be safely published to those multiple threads (that is, published without data races)?

Comment: Yes, it would only be published after it's been fully loaded in a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (of the presented options) option number 2 is likely to be far more efficient.

A [`CuncurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) per the Javadoc, provides *A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.*

It has to perform work to provide that, just keep the immutable `Map` instance and let multiple readers access it.

Comment: OK - and just reading the `HashMap<>` when wrapped with the unmodifiableMap view should not have any side effects?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try an [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)? Once created cannot be modified so doesn't matter how many threads try to read in parallel.

Comment: What would the advantage be over option 2?

Comment: According to the documentation, "Unlike Collections.unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map<? extends K, ? extends V>), which is a view of a separate map which can still change, an instance of ImmutableMap contains its own data and will never change"

Comment: Yeah, but he was going to get rid of the original map anyways.

Comment: Well, there are definitely multiple ways to achieve what the OP wants, this is just one of them. Which best serves the purpose, only the OP can answer that :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would consider it, but it does not seem to offer any advantage over option two :)

Comment: [ImmutableMap does not take excess memory](https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures) as mutable HashMap does.